# Casting between two similar nested classes - Stripe Java SDK

Tags: java, generics, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe's Java SDK and I notice two classes

```
com.stripe.param.AccountCreateParams.Individual.Address
com.stripe.param.AccountCreateParams.Company.Address
```

Both of them have the exact same properties, builder code etc. AccountCreateParams is the main class and Individual and Company are defined within AccountCreateParams. The source code can be seen [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stripe/param/AccountCreateParams.java)

Is it possible to cast from Individual.Address to Company.Address and vice versa? My end goal is to write only a single method like the following without writing separate code for each class

```
public <either individual or company Address> createAddress(myObject, String classtype){
     <Dynamically Figure out Class> stripeClass = <Dynamically Figure out Class>.builder().
                                         .setCity(myObject.getCity)
                                         .build();
     return stripeClass;

}
```

Comment: These classes are similar but not related, you cannot cast them into each other.

Comment: Take `class A {}` and `class B {}` you cannot cast an instance of `A` to `B` or vice-versa because they are in no direct way related. Even though they "look" and "feel" the same (both contain nothing). Java does **not** allow [Duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)!

Comment: I thought maybe there would be a workaround since both of them were nested within AccountCreateParams but I guess that doesn't make a difference

Comment: You could extend both classes via your own classes and make those extended classes abide by a contract defined via an interface. Then your function merely accepts objects of the interface-type which appies to both extended classes.